# Having trouble to connect to the chat

Tags: support, chat

For two days last week, I had trouble accessing the chat. The site either wouldn't load, or wouldn't load fully, or render awfully (see below), or I couldn't post messages... I only had trouble when doing so from work while it was fine from home, it was worse in the mornings (GMT+1) and better in the evenings, FF was worse than IE, all of stackoverflow.com was fine, only the chat acted up.

Since it's only been bad from work, I put it down to some quirk in my company's Internet connection. However, as I found out later, [others had this problem](http://twitter.com/#!/klmr/status/44468220266160128), too, and it was only Germans reporting it.

The trouble is, it's back today.

Anyone else having trouble accessing the chat?

---

[image: awful rendering]

---

[image: C++ room not loading]

---

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Maybe it's a provider issue - maybe ask @Konrad who he's with.

Comment: @Pekka: [He's with 1&1](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/433078#433078)

Comment: who is yours?

Comment: @Pekka: Yep, cleaning the cache didn't help. here at work http is routed to Vodafone (which is Arcor really). (Some of the other traffic is routed through QSC, so if there's other protocoly involved, I'd have to check with the syd admins.)

Answer (score 3):

[Our](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131182/kyle-brandt) [sysadmins](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140512/zypher) just told me something very complicated about "confused heartbeats in Oregon" that *might* have caused these issues.

Please observe for a little bit; I'd appreciate feedback whether this appears to be solved or not.

Comment: I hadn't any issues in the afternoon, when I started chatting [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/433604#433604). Now I'm home and I never had any troubles from here, neither morning nor evening. I'll keep you posted if I see this again. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: balpha, it seems this morning everything was fine, but when I wanted to look whether the blog has something new I found I couldn't access http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ until I tried about 30-60mins ago. Thought you'd like to know.

Comment: balpha, my problems are back, must have happened in the last 30mins. Both the chat and the blog give trouble, the rest of the web (including SO proper) seems fine. See anything on your end?

Comment: @sbi - can you run a tracert and post your results as an answer when you are having trouble?  I'd like to know about tracert to both chat.stackexchange.com and or.sstatic.net - thanks!

Comment: @Geoff: I'm not sure this would help. http traffic is routed different than those tracing packets here. Do you want to see it nevertheless?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone else having trouble accessing the chat?

For me, it's the other way around: I have constantly trouble at home, but never at work so far.

Now that I think about it, I could just connect via VPN to my workplace... yup, it works :)